# Display value of QByteArray

Tags: qt, serial-port, qbytearray

I am making simple serial communication app. Connection works well and I send data from my device to my app i am getting in log when I do qDebug() << dataByte:

```
"\x0B"
"\x0B"
```

Now I want to display this in a QTextEdit as "0B" string. How do I go about doing that? I read about QTextCodec but that is to convert 0B into a character which is not what I want.

Pls show me some guide thank you.

EDIT: I also tried

```
QString DataAsString = dataByte.toStdString();
```

But error comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok nvm I found the answer

```
QString DataAsString = data.toHex();
```